# How can I implement cd command in my own shell in C without using the chdir() function?

Tags: c, shell, cd, chdir

I have been searching for a code for implementing the **cd command using C in my own shell**. However, every code uses the chdir() inbuilt function of C to change the directory. I wanted to know how I can implement cd **without using chdir()**. Or atleast the **code for chdir()** itself.

Comment: Why can't you use `chdir()`?

Comment: My Professor wants us to do the whole thing from scratch. Or atleast know how exactly do the inbuilt functions work (that is why i need the code for chdir).

Comment: `chdir` only changes the current directory. So your shell must maintain a variable that is the "current dir". Any `cd` command now changes this variable; anything needing the current dir uses this variable. That's all.

Comment: *My Professor wants us to do the whole thing from scratch.*  You **can't** change the current working directory of your process without making the `chdir()` call (on just about all systems, anyway).  The current working directory is a property of the process, and it can only be changed by the kernel - which means you have to call `chdir()`.  The best you can do is (maybe) do the system call directly (if that's possible in your OS).

Comment: What  @PaulOgilvie said or use `fchdir()`.

Comment: It depends on what your shell should be able to do. If you care only about the interpretation of relative file names you might be able to replace the effect of `chdir` by converting all relative file names to absolute ones based on your own "current directory" variable.

Comment: Remember, you can't use `printf` or `putchar` or `write` either, because it's from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The current directory for a process is maintained by the kernel, so you need a syscall to change it.